# How to merge rows with same string, but sum up the rows connected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
| name | number |
|------|--------| 
| a    | 1      |
| a    | 1      |
| a    | 1      |
| b    | 2      |
| b    | 2      |
| b    | 2      |
| c    | 3      |
| c    | 3      |
| c    | 3      |
| d    | 4      |
| d    | 4      |
| d    | 4      |
```

I wish to merge all the rows by string, but have their number value added up and kept in line with the name..

Output desired..

```
| name | number |
|------|--------| 
| a    | 3      |
| b    | 6      |
| c    | 9      |
| d    | 12     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['number'].sum()
#or
#df = df.groupby('name')['number'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DataFrame is your table name

```
Select name, SUM(number) [number] FROM DataFrame GROUP BY name
```

Insert the result after deleting the original rows

Comment: `DataFrame` is a python type from pandas library. No database in sight.